# Can't post my 50th question in 30 days

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I can't post the latest question because, as it says, I'm only allowed 50 in a 30-day period. I agree, it's been a slow Christmas - home alone on crutches bored as a donkey - but then I went to count. And I claim that SO is wrong.

In fact, my 49th latest question was on January 1st (*Converting an int...*), while the 50th latest was on December 29th (*Is there any...*). The way I calculate, it's time to smack down a new question as I've only had 49 the last 30 days.

Am I missing something? It doesn't count against Meta question and questions on other sites, does it?

Comment: @cybermonkey 50 question isn't a lot if you're not at work and can't do usual stuff away from computer. Besides, what's your point - there's rule of 50 questions in 30 days (most of them with upvotes, so the quality is quite good). The rule seems not to work.

Comment: You have a [question from January 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685613/why-is-json-via-rest-skipping-spaces-in-the-output-of-a-string) which you deleted.

Comment: @animuson Ah, those **are not** shown in the question list! Well, there we go! Mystery resolved. I'd count your reply as the answer, in fact. Do you want to do the honors, should I or is it not very relevant at all?

Comment: Maybe is not the case, but one more think to consider is the time zone. If I am not mistaken,  StackOverflow uses UTC time.

Comment: I took the liberty of checking some of your recent questions. On the whole I have to say they're good; clear, well-written and on-topic. The only thing I notice is a few could have been answered by searching a little more (for example here are a couple which I was able to find answers to using simple Google searches for your key terms: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34634039/1180785, http://stackoverflow.com/q/35001541/1180785). I wouldn't say you're doing wrong, but since this limit exists, spending more time searching seems like it would help you avoid it in the future (it's often faster too!)

Comment: (also, 50 questions in 30 days might be the letter-of-the-law, but the intent is clearly a rate-limiter. If it's out by 1 or ambiguous on timezones, it wouldn't be a surprise)

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the feed-back. It makes me glad that you find my questions well-placed. As for the research part, I can agree that on a few occasions, I missed a pre-existing question. To my defense I must say that I **always** make a research before asking a question (although maybe not always successfully) and most of the times, there's no such resource or - commonly - to get to the resource I need a better problem diagnostics, which I can't have until I've asked. But in a few cases, I did made a booboo. True that. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Deleted questions are not shown in the question list. As the moderator said in the comments:

> You have a question from January 8 which you deleted.